# Undo/redo in Outlook, message body history

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, microsoft-outlook-2016

[My Computer: Win.10; 2016 MS Microsoft; Lenovo Laptop;]

In the process of highlighting a letter in an email in MS Outlook to copy it, I accidentally deleted the entire message body, leaving behind only the subject line: “Report to Dr. XX”.

I believe that I immediately used Undo, but it didn’t work!

I then searched just about everywhere in and out of OneDrive and all my folders and subfolders by "Find", and all I found was only the subject line with an empty body, and saw the same thing within my Personal Vault in OneDrive.

This is a most important medical letter.  I was working on it in the Draft folder for couple of weeks to perfect it,  which means it was automatically saved in Draft by Outlook, yet not there!

I hope someone here could tell me what else to do to find it.  I don't know how to search the hard drive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-your-onedrive-fa231298-759d-41cf-bcd0-25ac53eb8a15 doesn't help, perhaps contact MS OneDrive Support: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/#! (expand list to see OneDrive). There were issues at OneDrive on June 8 - https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/onedrive

Comment: Read through this post to see if anything there is helpful in your situation: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-recover-earlier-saved-draft-email-versions/2815a768-fb13-4aa7-b2cf-348f897fd30b

Comment: I have bad news, the letter is permanently gone, there isn’t a solution to your problem

Comment: How did you highlight a letter in MS Outlook? Will it happen again when you do the same operation on other emails?

Comment: MS Word and other Office products have undo IF you've saved them and you're using OneDrive, using versioning built in to OneDrive. Outlook emails do not have versioning, and if you've cleared/reset the undo/redo buffers you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

While MS Word, Excel, and PowerPoint have undo IF you've saved the file already and you're using OneDrive, using versioning built in to OneDrive, Outlook emails do not have versioning and file history in the same way because they are not saved in the same way.

If you have cleared/reset the undo/redo buffers by typing or switching focus after the accidental deletion, you're out of luck.